# Can regex queries be combined in SAS?

Tags: regex, sas, enterprise-guide

I've successfully implemented a negative lookback in my regex code in SAS. However, there are multiple 'words' that are possibilities that would negate the string I'm looking for. Specifically I'm looking for a phrase (from medical notes) that say "carbapenmase producing" or "carbapenamase confirmed" and at times these phrases can be preceded by "not carbapenemase producing" or "possible carbapenamase producing", and these I don't want. Having learned that negative lookbacks require the qualifier words (if > 1) to be of the same length, I need to create 2 separate regex expressions to capture "not" and "possible", as in:

```
*!!! Create template to identify key phrases in the comment/note;
retain carba1 carba2 carba3;
if _n_ = 1 then do;     /*probable*/
 carba1 = prxparse("/(?<!not\s)ca[bepr]\w*?\s*?(conf|posi|prod|\+)/i");
 carba2 = prxparse("/(?<!possible|probable\s)ca[bepr]\w*?\s*? 
 (conf|posi|prod|\+)/i");
 carba3 = prxparse("/(?<!not a\s)ca[bepr]\w*?\s*?(conf|posi|prod|\+)/i");
end;

if prxmatch(carba1,as_comments) > 0 or prxmatch(carba2,as_comments) > 0 or
prxmatch(carba3,as_comments) > 0;
```

Is there a word around for this that would shorten execution time, or am I stuck with this? Any advice/comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if it has just 4 scenarios and they are straightforward. you can do this simple by using contains and not contains.

```
data have;
length string $200.;
infile datalines;
input string & $ ;
datalines;
this is cool and carbapenmase producing or  wow so nice
this is wow confirmed carbapenamase confirmed hello
now this positive for modified hodge test and later 
cool is my name not carbapenemase producing" or "the modified hodge hello
wow and wow previous possible carbapenamase producing hello
 Mr cool is hello
;


 data want;
  set have;
    where (string contains "carbapenmase producing" or
     string contains "carbapenamase confirmed")
   and  not (string contains "not carbapenemase producing" or 
   string contains "possible carbapenamase producing");
  run;
```